# How to put content of binary file in a string in c?

Tags: c, binaryfiles

How can I put content of a binary file in a string?

I'm using C.

Comment: You can put it in a variable, but it won't be a string. Strings are text with 0 terminator, and binary files may have 0 in the middle.

Comment: Use the `fread()` function.

Comment: Strings in C are also made up of `char`s, which may or may not be signed. Use `unsigned char` or `uint8_t` from `<stdint.h>` for binary data. Because there is no delimiter, you have to keep an extra variable for the length.

Comment: You right, so how can i put it in char[]?

Comment: I've heard about fread() and fwrite(), but i don't know how to use it, can you write me a simple code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `fread`:

```
unsigned char buf[MAX_FILE_READ_SIZE];

FILE* fp = fopen("file", "rb");
size_t bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);
```

About putting it in a "string" - do you maybe want a text representation of the file's bytes? If yes, you could then do:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
{
    printf("%X ", buf[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank's, i mean to put in in char[].